# xmppp android get message from iQ parser

Tags: android

```
 1. This is my my response stanza 
2. my filter is like 
StanzaFilter filterIq = new StanzaTypeFilter(IQ.class);
            connection.addSyncStanzaListener(new IQMessageListener(),filterIq);

3. Stanza listener 
 private class IQMessageListener implements StanzaListener {

        @Override
        public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
          IQ iq = (IQ) packet;
            //List<ExtensionElement> extensionElements= iq.getExtensions();

            if (iq.hasExtension("http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub")) {
                ExtensionElement pubSubExtension =iq.getExtension("http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub");
}
}
}
```

5. %7B%0A%20%20%22message_time%22%20:%20%221465289063.462249%22,%0A%20%20%22message_type%22%20:%20%22u%22,%0A%20%20%22message_text_data%22%20:%20%22Hi%22,%0A%20%20%22group_server_id%22%20:%20%22163AC7D9-37DF-4CAA-830B-DCBECD3C1E7B%22,%0A%20%20%22message_from%22%20:%20%228686519203834172%22,%0A%20%20%22mime_type%22%20:%20%22t%22%0A%7D
                    
                    
                       %7B%0A%20%20%22message_time%22%20:%20%221465289769.662461%22,%0A%20%20%22message_type%22%20:%20%22u%22,%0A%20%20%22message_text_data%22%20:%20%22Hi%5CnSend%22,%0A%20%20%22group_server_id%22%20:%20%220D0FDDA2-8C97-4850-B2B8-04F5F7896721%22,%0A%20%20%22message_from%22%20:%20%228686519203834172%22,%0A%20%20%22mime_type%22%20:%20%22t%22%0A%7D
                    
            
                       %7B%0A%20%20%22message_text_data%22%20:%20%22So%22,%0A%20%20%22message_type%22%20:%20%22u%22,%0A%20%20%22message_from%22%20:%20%2215587183095259626%22,%0A%20%20%22group_server_id%22%20:%20%228B831363-5A84-4FEE-AB13-0EAE21A89C16%22,%0A%20%20%22message_time%22%20:%20%221468237398.799048%22,%0A%20%20%22mime_type%22%20:%20%22t%22%0A%7D

   2. How i can get message from this stanza in android application

      3. i am using smack library.

Answer (score -1):

If your not using any library for XMPP, then you will have to write your own XML parser for this, which is not very difficult.
But I would suggest to use SMACK library for this, which will help you with other types of messages too. You can easily write a parser and a listener for your customised IQ.
And looking at your IQ, Smack has a ready made API for it. So that should make it easier for you.
Below is a sample packet filter and collector

```
PacketFilter packetFilter = new IQReplyFilter(pubsubIQ, xmppConn);
// Create the packet collector before sending the packet
PacketCollector packetCollector = xmppConn.createPacketCollector(packetFilter);
IQ responseIQ = (IQ) packetCollector.nextResult(PACKET_TIMEOUT);
packetCollector.cancel();
```

The responseIQ above is what you need, and what your provider will return, you will have to cast it to your IQ.

Comment: Can you show and example - more useful to everybody especially if it's to be considered an answer

Comment: Can you provide API name for this

Comment: Under PubSubProvider there is parseIQ(). which will parse this for you, you can customise it if you are extending its functionality.
Does this answer your question @dbmitch ?

Comment: The person asking the question may need more details. I'm just saying that if you're going to propose an answer please make it detailed enough so that it can be consider an actual solution

Comment: @ArjunDev : add your provider using this ProviderManager.addIQProvider("your_tag", "your_namespace", new CustomIQProvider()); you will have to create CustomIQProvider according to your need.

Comment: hoe can use in smak Example 78. Subscriber requests all items
<iq type='get'
    from='francisco@denmark.lit/barracks'
    to='pubsub.shakespeare.lit'
    id='items1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <items node='princely_musings'/>
  </pubsub>
</iq>

Comment: Can you be more specific or share some code where you want help. You want to request all items?